# notify client when session times out while waiting on callback from the service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soa

I have a service oriented desktop application.

I am doing a call to a service for a particular action and then waiting for a callback from the service. If the service action takes more time to complete than the session timeout value, I get an exception on the service. But the client keep waiting for the callback.

Is there a way that the client can get notified that the session has timed out?

Comment: Would it not be easier to impliment as way to renew the active session?   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/baefef0f-0f17-44d1-8990-aa517c2e2929/

Comment: Sorry I somehow missed pasting the rest, as well as implementing an active session you could update the user every every N number of minutes, using some form of background timer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I guess you would want to catch the exception and work accordingly (like returning the callback with an invalid session message?).

Also, you could implement timeout on the callback async waiting, so even when the session is expired or the network is out or the Apocalypse destroys network communications your client can turn back control and inform the user.

*"Please log in again and try, verify your network and check for any signs of the end of days."*

**EDIT**: As requested by feedback, here goes a little more detail on my thoughts about the server-client interaction you should have.

The main problem you're facing is that some event happens (session expiration, or unexpected failure) that prevents the client from knowing the server won't ever answer back. You can't plan for catastrophic failures, but you sure can plan for invalid sessions, invalid authentications, invalid data and so forth. In such cases, the server should probably be more verbose, specially if you're working with a thin-client model that will stay doing nothing until the server pings back.

But then, how to handle the real failures, when communication is not happening? If you can consider that communication errors can happen (and I would really suggest you do so), you should make your client intelligent enough at least to handle communication errors. It is important that such a thing is done because, first of all, communications are not that reliable (misconfigurations happen, hardware failures, etc). Secondly, when such a thing happens, you are risking your functionality to dissapear, or providing a real poor user experience. Not that errors are a good user experience, but more responsive applications are.

**TL;DR:** Provide feedback to the client side, and user if needed. It is important that both *know* what happens.

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, but this answer doesn't seem to provide any helpful insight and to me is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (appreciated indeed). I guess I must be missing something then, I see no reason why feedback from server to client would be a good approach here. // EDIT: I guess I know what you mean, I'll make an effort to give a more explanative answer. Thanks.

Comment: well see if I got it right, let's suppose you have several clients and a service. Each client asks a service to do some (perhaps long enough) work. Then each client wants to get a feedback when this work is complete. The server needs to notify clients and provide some results. If the operation times out on the server, the client may not *(I am not sure about this, but it looks like that)* receive any notification, as the channel is closed on the server, but the client keeps waiting. OP wants a client to get notified in this particular case.

Comment: Based on your comment, I haven't considered the case where the timeout is happening on the server-side. I thought the definition of timeout here was the sesssion for the user, which would be shared between server and client.
As for this case, my second recommendation still holds, which is for clients to be intelligent enough to handle long waits as failures.

Comment: yep I think it's possible to do via config file, but also there might be some events (like Closed/Faulted) on the client side. But I am not too sure how to do that. It's just upsetting that some people get lazy to explain why they downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using sessions? If you are doing callback with wsDualHttpBinding then you need to use sessions, but if you are using netTcpBinding then you don't need sessions. So then there will be no time out.